# How can I display only one camera view option in a custom pie menu?

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

`pie.operator_enum("VIEW3D_OT_viewnumpad", "type")` - this gives list of views.
 I want only one "camera" button , not all from the enum (front, left, right etc.). How can I do it?

`bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad(type='CAMERA')` - this isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

`pie.operator("VIEW3D_OT_viewnumpad").type='CAMERA'` - this is right

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer, otherwise it might get deleted.